AuthJS FACEIT Provider unexpected ID returned
I'm trying to integrate FACEIT oAuth2 into my website using authjs5, but when I try to login I get this error:  Unexpected ID Token returned, use processAuthorizationCodeOpenIDResponse() for OpenID Connect callback processing
I set this as the redirect url on faceit: {URL}/api/auth/callback/faceit
My auth.ts file:
import NextAuth from "next-auth" import FACEIT from "next-auth/providers/faceit" 
export const { handlers, signIn, signOut, auth } = NextAuth({   providers: [FACEIT], })  

My /app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts file:
import { handlers } from "@/auth" export const { GET, POST } = handler  

